# What is a current/good Mass Estimating Equation/Heuristic for space radiators/heating systems?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, thermal, thermal-control

Has anyone does any analysis for thermal control systems for manned space habitats? I know Gilmore has data for unmanned systems, but I was looking for data for unmanned systems, preferably to develop MERs (mass estimating relations)?